Deserialize Message from EventHub using Kafka Streaming in Python
I am new into Kafka and I am trying to read Stream events coming from an Azure EventHub using python but I am not able to correctly deserialize the data.
kafka_options = {
    # Port 9093 is the EventHubs Kafka port
    "kafka.bootstrap.servers": f"{event_hubs_server}:9093",
    "kafka.sasl.jaas.config": sasl_config,
    "kafka.sasl.oauthbearer.token.endpoint.url": f"https://login.microsoft.com/{tenant_id}/oauth2/v2.0/token",
    "subscribe": event_hubs_topic,
    "kafka.security.protocol": "SASL_SSL",
    "kafka.sasl.mechanism": "OAUTHBEARER",
    "startingOffsets":"earliest",
    "kafka.sasl.login.callback.handler.class": "org.apache.kafka.common.security.oauthbearer.secured.OAuthBearerLoginCallbackHandler",
    "maxOffsetsPerTrigger": 1000
}

df = spark.readStream.format("kafka").options(**kafka_options).load()

I am not producing the events and I only know that they are produced using EventHub Producer client in .NET, I also created a EventHub Consumer client and I am able to consume the events and looks like this:
{ body: '<read-error>', properties: {b'Id': b'8e80c7936410',b'End': b'2024-04-01T01:37:45', b'Start': b'2024-04-01T01:37:34', b'CreateTime': 1711937065945}, offset: 562640835552, sequence_number: 79685, partition_key=b'8c76b8ed-82ca-4b43-a323-8e80c7936410', enqueued_time=datetime.datetime(2024, 4, 1, 2, 4, 26, 349000, tzinfo=datetime.timezone.utc) }

When I am reading the event using Kafka I getting the binary values in 'key' and 'value' fields.
Output from Kafka StreamRead:


--------------------+--------------------+-----+---------+------+--------------------+-------------+
|                 key|               value|topic|partition|offset|           timestamp|timestampType|
+--------------------+--------------------+-----+---------+------+--------------------+-------------+
|[64 38 65 61 39 3...|[4B C6 AD 98 A9 1...|prd1 |      106| 79856|2024-03-31 20:18:...|            0|


I tried to parse the binary fields into string using df.selectExpr("CAST(value AS STRING)") and F.base64(col("value").cast("string")))  but the output is still showing unreadable text.
+--------------------+------------------+----------+---------+------+--------------------+-------------+
|                 key|             value|     topic|partition|offset|           timestamp|timestampType|
+--------------------+------------------+----------+---------+------+--------------------+-------------+
|[64 38 65 61 39 3...|   Kƭ��zN��{�t�H|prd1      |      106| 79856|2024-03-31 20:18:...|            0|

I tried using custom schema but the result is just showing null values.
schema = StructType([
    StructField("body", StringType(), True),
    StructField("properties", StringType(), True),
    StructField("offset", LongType(), True),
    StructField("sequence_number", LongType(), True),
    StructField("partition_key", StringType(), True),
    StructField("enqueued_time", StringType(), True)
])

df.withColumn("decoded_properties", from_json(col("value").cast("string"), schema)) \
    .select("decoded_properties.*")


Are the events consumed by Kafka will look like the ones consumed by the EventHub Consumer client? Could you advice me on how to deserialize the 'value' field.

Please edit your previous question with what you've tried, rather than create a similar post, and again without seeing how the producer is written, this isn't answerable. The fact that it's a .NET client isn't really important
